# Extensions: Auto Check Updates but only once per day?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know there is a setting `Extensions: Auto Check Updates` (and I have it enabled).  I'm just wondering if there is a way to only have it check once per day, or the first time I start VSC each day?

Not a huge deal of course, I just find the mid-day notification distracting, so I always click to update the extensions, which takes me out of what I'm working on.  I could also just disable the auto check, but I like to keep the extensions up to date.  Once per day would be enough for me.

Thanks!